# 429 Errors during Azure Deployment for EventHub

Tags: azure, deployment, azure-resource-manager, azure-eventhub, azure-bicep

I am deploying an Bicep template which contains a number of IPFilterRules and other network resources.

During the Deployment each individual resource is getting a 429 error, it then retries a minute later and some more succeed and some more fail and then eventually after 5-10 minutes they all succeed.

Here is an example of how I'm creating my ip filter rules:

```
resource EventHubNamespace 'Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces@2021-06-01-preview' = {
  // ...
  resource IpFilterRules 'ipfilterrules@2018-01-01-preview' = [for ip in companyIps: {
    name: uniqueString(resourceGroup().name, ip)
    properties: {
      action: 'Accept'
      ipMask: ip
    }
  }]
}
```

Here is what the Deployment panel looks like while erroring:

[image: 429 errors]

How can I prevent these 429 errors from happening? Can I increase some limit to allow for a more resources? Or is there a way to alter my bicep template so these resources are created 1 at a time instead of all at once? Or is there any other technique I could use to speed up this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run the ip rules resource sequentially by using the [batchSize decorator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/bicep/file#resource-and-module-decorators):

```bicep
resource EventHubNamespace 'Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces@2021-06-01-preview' = {
  ...
}

@batchSize(1)
resource IpFilterRules 'Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/ipfilterrules@2018-01-01-preview' = [for ip in companyIps: {
  name: uniqueString(resourceGroup().name, ip)
  parent: EventHubNamespace
  properties: {
    action: 'Accept'
    ipMask: ip
  }
}]
```

To apply the configuration at once, you could use a [networkRuleSets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.eventhub/2021-06-01-preview/namespaces/networkrulesets?tabs=bicep):

```bicep
resource NetworkRuleSet 'Microsoft.EventHub/namespaces/networkRuleSets@2021-06-01-preview' = {
  name: 'default'
  parent: EventHubNamespace
  properties: {
    defaultAction: 'Allow'
    ipRules: [for ip in companyIps: {
      action: 'Allow'
      ipMask: ip
    }]
    publicNetworkAccess: 'Enabled'
    trustedServiceAccessEnabled: true
    virtualNetworkRules: []
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried the batchSize trick also and that did indeed fix it! 2 is too many but 1 works. I will definitely try the RuleSets version next though. But with the sequential install its no longer the slowest resource (kubernetes is) so its not an emergency, but thanks!